# Custom Cell for 2 TableViews/Segmented Control Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uitableview

So I have a Segmented Control that switches between 2 TableViews & 1 MapView inside a MainVC.

I'm able to switch the views in the simulator by adding an IBAction func changedInSegmentedControl to switch which views are hidden while one of them is active.

I created 2 custom TableViewCells with XIBs. I also added tags with each TableView.

My question is how do I add them in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Currently, my code is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
  {
    // var cell: UITableViewCell
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
      cell: CardTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CardCell") as! CardTableViewCell
return cell
      }
    else if (tableView.tag == 2) {
      cell: ListTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListCell") as! ListTableViewCell
return cell
    }
  }
```

Of course Swift requires a "return cell" for the function outside the If statements. I tried with a var cell: UITableViewCell outside, but run into trouble finishing the dequeuReusableCellWithIdentifier.

Anyone have some idea how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I approached it (Swift 3.0 on iOS 10).   I made one tableView with two custom cells (each is their own subclass). The segmented control is on my navigationBar and has two segments: People and Places.

There are two arrays within my class, (people and places) which are the data sources for the two table views.  An action attached to the segmentedControl triggers the reload of the table, and the switch statement in `cellForRowAtIndex` controls which cell from which array is loaded.

I load data into the two data arrays from an API call, the asynchronous completion of which triggers `dataLoaded()`, which reloads the tableView. Again I don't have to worry about which segment is selected when the table is reloaded: `cellForRowAtIndex` takes care of loading the correct data. 
I initialize a basic cell just as UITableViewCell and then in the case statement I created and configure the custom cell. Then I return my custom type cell at the end, and as long as the reuseIdentifiers and classes are correct in `cellForRowAtIndex`, the correct cell is initialized and displayed in the tableView.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var peoplePlacesControl: UISegmentedControl!

fileprivate var placesArray: [PlaceModel]?
fileprivate var usersArray: [UserModel]?


@IBAction func segmentedControlActionChanged(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    tableView.reloadData()
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0: 
        loadUsersfromAPI()
    case 1: 
        loadPlacesFromAPI()
    default:
        // shouldnt get here
        return
    }
}


func dataLoaded() {
    switch peoplePlacesControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0: // users
        if favoriteUsersArray == nil {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            hideTableViewWhileEmpty()
        }
    case 1: // places
        if placesArray != nil {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            hideTableViewWhileEmpty()
        }
    default: 
        return
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:  
        if usersArray != nil {
            return usersArray!.count
        } else {
            return 0 
        }
    case 1:  // places
        if placesArray != nil {
            return placesArray!.count
        } else {
            return 0  
        }
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    switch peoplePlacesControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:  // people
        let userCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyUserCell", for: indexPath) as! MyUserTableViewCell
        if usersArray != nil && indexPath.row < usersArray!.count {
            let user = usersArray![indexPath.row]
            userCell.configure(user)
            userCell.myDelegate = self
        }
        cell = userCell as MyUserTableViewCell

    case 1:  // places
        let placeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyPlaceCell", for: indexPath) as! MyPlaceTableViewCell

        if favoritePlacesArray != nil && indexPath.row < favoritePlacesArray!.count {
            let place = placesArray![indexPath.row]
            placeCell.configure(place)
            placeCell.myDelegate = self
        }
        cell = placeCell as MyPlaceTableViewCell

    default:
        break
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: How Cell register either nib or prototype cell in storyboard? I registered two different cells in tableview.

Comment: @27J91, if you are using a storyboard, you can put the reuse identifier string in the Interface Builder field `reuseIdentifier` of each prototype cell. This is what I did in my example, as I was using a storyboard. Alternatively, you can also register prototype cells programmatically by saying (in `viewDidLoad`) `tableView.registerClass(cellClass:MyUserTableViewCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: "UserCellReuseIdentifier")`. As long as you register a reuseIdentifier for each your cells, the UITableView will be able to dequeue your two different kinds of reusable cells when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have made change in your code.
**Use following code**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {

        cell: CardTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CardCell") as! CardTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

    cell: ListTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListCell") as! ListTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I tried that before. Got compiler error "Type 'UITableViewCell' does not conform to protocol NilLiteralConvertible.